# How to use jQuery's "data" to uncheck a checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.7.1

I am trying to access several items on a page with microdata attribute "data-prodid".  I am told that I should be using jQuery's "data" property, but I can't get it to work correctly.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-prodid="12345">
```

On a click event, the checkbox is unchecked:

```
// UNCHECK ITEM IN LIST
var Product_ID = $(this).data("prodid");
$(".Product[data-prodid="+Product_ID+"]").attr("checked", false);
```

How do I rewrite these so that something like this works using jQuery's "data" attribute?

```
// UNCHECK ITEM IN LIST
var Product_ID = $(this).data("prodid");
$(".Product").data("prodid").eq(Product_ID).data("checked", false);
$(".Product").data("prodid", Product_ID).attr("checked", false);
```

Is there really a right way or a wrong way to do this?

Comment: There most certainly is a wrong way to do this, and thinking that jQuery's data() will access the actual data attribute of your element is probably one of those wrong ways, read the documentation?

Comment: You mean `.data` *method*, you'll end up with a longer implementation if you use that.

Comment: I would suggest using `prop()` instead of `attr()`. AFAIK you use `attr('disabled', 'disabled')` and `prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: @Johan, I studied up on prop(), data(), and attr(). I am now using them appropriately.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect case for using the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
var productID = $(this).data("prodid");
var $relatedProducts = $('.product').filter(function() { 
  return $(this).data("prodid") == productID;
});
$relatedProducts.attr("checked", false);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hzSV6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[data-prodid='12345']").attr("checked", false);
```

Comment: Please add a little explaination ;)

Answer (score 0):

This could work:On Click or Change function get the data from the checkbox ,check it and using attr make it false.

```
            $(".test").click(function() {
              var productID = $(this).data("prodid");
              $("input[data-prodid="+productID+"]").attr("checked", false);
            }
```